# fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Box property calculation requires containing block width'

Tags: php, dompdf

When I try to process  url `http://www.bbc.co.uk/` dompdf throws error

```
fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Box property calculation requires containing block width'   in www\dompdf\include\block_frame_reflower.cls.php on line 171
```

It seems some settings or some bug?

Comment: It's definitely a bug. But let's disregard that fact for a moment. Why are you trying to render the BBC home page to PDF? If you're testing out dompdf for your own project it's better to do so in an environment closer to your use case (i.e. with the HTML/CSS on your site). And if rendering the BBC is your use case then it's fair to say that dompdf is not quite ready for that type of work. dompdf has not yet attained a level of stability and flexibility that is comparable to web browsers (though that is the ultimate goal). If you need browser-class rendering check out wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @BrianS   i have a problem . wants to make pdf from url http://google.com/ ... if wkhtmltopdf is perfect. and i also wants to test it on local host. can you give me a tutorial or web refrence which could help me..

Comment: why woudn't use google :) https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=wkhtmltopdf&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMPDF_Exception` is an extension of the `Exception` class. I'm not sure what parameters it will spit out, but you can dump the array out to see what is being returned:

```
try{

}catch(DOMPDF_Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>',print_r($e),'</pre>';
}
```

Also found this on Google Code that might help you narrow down, what the actual issue is: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=244

Answer (score 0):

No, you just have to catch exceptions or set your stuff properly.

```
try {
  //Do your stuff here
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->message() ;
}
```

Comment: why do I need exceptions? I need to know what to set to avoid this exception

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to return the message is

```
try {
  //Do your stuff here
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage() ;
}
```